# java application

Tags: java, sockets

For a java application:Why isn't there possible to start two different threads in the same main???

One thread that is listening form incoming connections to a port and another thread that listens for other connections to a totally different port???

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         ClientThread clienThread= new ClientThread();
        new Thread(clienThread).start();

        ThreadPooledServer server = new ThreadPooledServer(6000);
        new Thread(server).start();
    }
```

Where ClientThread() and ThreadPooledServer() are two different threads!

### Question:Why doesn't java let me do that?

```
public class Start {

    Socket socket;
    private String  serverIpAddress="127.0.0.1";
    static Thread cThread;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         ClientThread clienThread= new ClientThread();
        new Thread(clienThread).start();

        ThreadPooledServer server = new ThreadPooledServer(6000);
        new Thread(server).start();




    }


}
```

---

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 6100);

                System.out.println("s-a creat");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Don't know about host");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err
                        .println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to host");
            }


        }
    }
```

---

```
public class ThreadPooledServer implements Runnable {

    protected int serverPort =6000;
    public static String SERVERIP = "127.0.0.1";
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected boolean isStopped = false;
    protected Thread runningThread = null;
    public static int clientconnection = 0;
    Vector<WorkerRunnable> workerList = null;

     protected ExecutorService threadPool =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public ThreadPooledServer(int port) {
        this.serverPort = port;
        workerList = new Vector<WorkerRunnable>();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openServerSocket();

        while (!isStopped()) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("Serverul asteapta clienti spre conectare");
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                clientconnection++;
                System.out.println("Serverul a acceptat clientul cu numarul:"
                        + clientconnection);
                // Log.d("Server:","s-a acceptat un nou client");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (isStopped()) {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
                    return;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection",
                        e);
            }
            // creare thread pt noul client conectat
            //WorkerRunnable workerRunnable = new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket);
            //Thread workerThread = this.threadPool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket));
            //workerThread.start();
            this.threadPool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket));
            //this.workerList.add(workerRunnable);
        }
        this.threadPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
    }

    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
            // stop thread-uri workers
            for (int i = 0; i < this.workerList.size(); i++) {
                WorkerRunnable worker = this.workerList.elementAt(i);
                worker.stop();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            InetSocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress(SERVERIP,
                    serverPort);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.bind(serverAddr);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 6000", e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {

    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    Scanner s = null;
    String longitude;
    String latitude;

    boolean stop = false;

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            System.out.println("O noua conexiune acceptata"
                    + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + "cu portul"
                    + clientSocket.getPort());

            Scanner is = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(
                    this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            while (!stop) {

                while (is.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        longitude = is.next();
                        latitude = is.next();
        System.out.println(longitude);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            is.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.stop = true;
    }
```

---

This is all I have!!!

EDIT:I moved the ClientThread code into a different class and I succeded to run my code,but now I can't get to create two sockets.

I mean it creates one but for the second one I get:

"Couldn't get I/O for the connection to host"

I assume that is coming from here:

```
 catch (IOException e) {

                System.err
                        .println("Couldn't get I/O for the 
connection to host");

        }
```

Does someone knows why??

Comment: What classes does ClientThread and ThreadPooledServer extend or implement?

Comment: Please post the stack trace you're getting from the exception.

Comment: Both implement Runnable!

Comment: Is not an exception...is error,I can't not even run my code!    It says:   No enclosing instance of type Start is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Start (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of 
 Start)......Start is the name of my class

Comment: That's a far different question than "Why isn't there possible to start two different threads in the same main?" Post your class source.

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo.....please....I cried because of this things...Are exactly the same!I'll edit my question with the entire code!

Comment: @mariana: You haven't posted any code which uses `Start`, which makes it pretty hard to diagnose the problem... you've used `ThreadPooledServer` and `ClientThread`. Please post a short but *complete* program.

Comment: Well,I think is megacomplete now.Thx

Comment: No, it's not complete. Where are you calling the constructor of Start?

Comment: I'm not using one.Why I need one?

Comment: because you've defined both client and server as inner classes (they're defined *inside* the start class).  so you can't create the "inner" things without the "outer" thing.  move those classes out to their own top level classes and you'd be fine.

Comment: yep,that was exactly what I did...and it works:D:D:DD:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threads or sockets.  The error you are getting is described [here](http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=No_enclosing_instance_of_type_Foo_is_accessible._Must_qualify_the_allocation_with_an_enclosing_instance_of_type_Foo_%28e.g._x.new_A%28%29_where_x_is_an_instance_of_Foo%29.).  Without seeing your code I'd say that the classes you are trying to instantiate are inner classes of Start.  You don't have an instance of Start because you're in its static main() method.

try something like:

```
public class Start
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Start myStart = new Start();
    myStart.doIt();
  }

  private void doIt()
  {
    ClientThread clienThread= new ClientThread();
    new Thread(clienThread).start();

    ThreadPooledServer server = new ThreadPooledServer(6000);
    new Thread(server).start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible to start as many Threads from main() as you wish (the OS might impose some limit).

Unfortunately my crystal ball is in repair, so I can only guess what might run wrong:
- another process is bound to port 6000 (maybe an old instance of your java program?)
- some synchronization in the Threads deadlocks them
- something else ;-)

Maybe you can clarify you problem?

Comment: Give me your address and I'll send u a crystal ball.....I can't guess where is my problem.I'm not that advanced.....the two threads are associated with different ports!!

Comment: the problem is a compile problem, not a runtime problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "No enclosing instance of type Start is accessible.":

Either create the treads in the constructor and create a new object of your class or declare the inner class static (if it does not need access to outer classes members)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback in the comment - 
"No enclosing instance of type Start is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Start (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Start"
 it appears that the class Start happens to be an inner class of some class X. Initializing an instance of an inner class is not as trivial as for an "ordinary class". One cannot initialize an inner class using the following notation:

```
Outer.Inner obj = new Outer.Inner();
```

Instead the following notation must be used:

```
Outer.Inner obj = outerObj.new Inner();
```

where `Outer` is the enclosing class and `Inner` is the enclosed class, and `outerObj` is an instance of the enclosing class.

PS: Please include more information in your questions to give anybody a chance at determining the problem. Your original question contains no information whatsoever that will aid in helping you out.